# How to set the number of y-axis values displayed when faceting

Tags: ggplot2, scale, facet, axis-labels, yaxis

I have a faceted bar graph.

```
 dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                   A = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2"),
                   B = c(1, 2, 53, 87, 200, 250))

 ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   facet_wrap(~ID, scales= "free_y")
```

How do I code to only have 3 y-axis values displayed per graph?

I've tried

```
   +scale_y_continuous(breaks=3)
```

Comment: You can try `scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 3)`, but 3 breaks is not guaranteed. It just outputs 3 breaks if the 3 breaks can be 'pretty'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more control over the breaks you can write your own breaks function. The following code gives you exactly 3 breaks. However, this very basic approach does not necessarily result in "pretty" breaks:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_breaks <- function(x) { 
  seq(0, round(max(x), 0), length.out = 3) 
} 

my_limits <- function(x) { 
  c(x[1], ceiling(x[2]))
}

# Dataset 2
dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
  A = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3","Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3"), 
  B = c(1.7388, 4.2059, .7751, .9489, 2.23405, .666589, 0.024459, 1.76190, 0.066678)) 

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales= "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks, limits = my_limits)
```

[image]

```r
# Dataset 1
dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                  A = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2"),
                  B = c(1, 2, 53, 87, 200, 250))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales= "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks, limits = my_limits)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks helpful and you are on the right track.  When I try to apply that to my  actual data set, it works for 8/10 facet plots, but for two plots it only labels 0.  Any idea what's causing that?

Comment: Example of problem:

     dat <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A","B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                       A = c("Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3","Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3"),
                       B = c(1.7388, 4.2059, .7751, .9489, 2.23405, .666589, 0.024459, 1.76190, 0.066678))

     my_breaks <- function(x) { 
       seq(0, pretty(max(x))[1], length.out = 3)
     }

     ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = A, y = B)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       facet_wrap(~ID, scales= "free_y")+
       scale_y_continuous(breaks = my_breaks)

Comment: Hi @KimberlyPeter. This is indeed a tricky one. I came up with a better solution, which at least for both of the given datasets now results in exactly three breaks. Revised `my_breaks`. However, the major change is to add a second function to ensure that all three breaks are within the axis limits.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it!  Thank you so much!